# How to connect to my PostgreSQL database on heroku with discord.py

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, discord.py

I have a discord bot and I host it on heroku . Recently I learned postgreSQL and it worked fine, now when I am trying to host the bot on heroku , I get this error:

```py
2020-11-16T08:24:23.418416+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-16T08:24:23.418448+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "Bot.py", line 113, in <module>
2020-11-16T08:24:23.418835+00:00 app[worker.1]:     client.loop.run_until_complete(create_db_pool())
2020-11-16T08:24:23.418864+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
2020-11-16T08:24:23.419318+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return future.result()
2020-11-16T08:24:23.419344+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "Bot.py", line 23, in create_db_pool
2020-11-16T08:24:23.419552+00:00 app[worker.1]:     client.pg_con= await asyncpg.create_pool(database="Abode", user="postgres", password="sugampanthi")
2020-11-16T08:24:23.419578+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 398, in _async__init__
2020-11-16T08:24:23.419923+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await self._initialize()
2020-11-16T08:24:23.419948+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 426, in _initialize
2020-11-16T08:24:23.420307+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await first_ch.connect()
2020-11-16T08:24:23.420347+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 125, in connect
2020-11-16T08:24:23.420569+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self._con = await self._pool._get_new_connection()
2020-11-16T08:24:23.420595+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 468, in _get_new_connection
2020-11-16T08:24:23.421007+00:00 app[worker.1]:     con = await connection.connect(
2020-11-16T08:24:23.421033+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1718, in connect
2020-11-16T08:24:23.421941+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return await connect_utils._connect(
2020-11-16T08:24:23.421967+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 674, in _connect
2020-11-16T08:24:23.422447+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise last_error
2020-11-16T08:24:23.422473+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 663, in _connect
2020-11-16T08:24:23.422996+00:00 app[worker.1]:     con = await _connect_addr(
2020-11-16T08:24:23.423021+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 632, in _connect_addr
2020-11-16T08:24:23.423453+00:00 app[worker.1]:     tr, pr = await asyncio.wait_for(
2020-11-16T08:24:23.423480+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 483, in wait_for
2020-11-16T08:24:23.423873+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return fut.result()
2020-11-16T08:24:23.423899+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1025, in create_connection
2020-11-16T08:24:23.424509+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise exceptions[0]
2020-11-16T08:24:23.424535+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1010, in create_connection
2020-11-16T08:24:23.425195+00:00 app[worker.1]:     sock = await self._connect_sock(
2020-11-16T08:24:23.425223+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 924, in _connect_sock
2020-11-16T08:24:23.425793+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
2020-11-16T08:24:23.425818+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 494, in sock_connect
2020-11-16T08:24:23.426253+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return await fut
2020-11-16T08:24:23.426279+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 526, in _sock_connect_cb
2020-11-16T08:24:23.426681+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
2020-11-16T08:24:23.426770+00:00 app[worker.1]: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 5432)
2020-11-16T08:24:23.576413+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-16T08:24:23.635986+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I don't whats wrong,
this is how I connect to postgres and it works when I run on my system,

```py
async def create_db_pool():
    bot.db = await asyncpg.create_pool(database="dbname",user="postgres",password="mypass")

bot.loop.run_until_complete(create_db_pool())
```

Comment: I tried this method a long time ago and rage quitted ! now Im using mongoDB as Database for my bot! just check that if you were unable to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to PostgreSQL on Heroku, you need to connect through the config variable called `DATABASE_URL`, not your local connection. You must have the Postgres add-on connected to your app first, though.